# one to many kind of implementation with apply in R

Tags: r, foreach, apply

I have to compare strings and check if they match approximately. My sample data looks like the below.

```
m6
PLOT#39 H#8-2-293/A4/A/
PLOT #39 H #8-2-293/A4/A
PLOT NO 1030 BUNGLOW NO
PLOT NO 1030 BUNGLOW NO
PLOT 1030 BUNGLOW NO 3
PLOT NO-39 H#8-2-293/A4/
GAYATRAI RESIDENCY MADHU
```

I am comparing each word of the first string to all the words in the second string. And like this I ended up writing 4 loops. It is taking long time to execute. I was thinking of apply functions but I am not sure how to use them in this case. So any ideas to improve the code will be greatly helpful. Thanks

```
    m <- strapply(m6, "(\\S+)", c)      
    for(i in 1:(length(m)-1)){      
        for(n in (i+1):(length(m))){            
            for(j in 1:length(m[[i]])){
                for(k in 1:length(m[[n]])){
                    if(length(agrep(m[[i]][j], m[[n]][k], ignore.case = TRUE))!= 0){
                        ....
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you describe the step "Check whether the two strings match approximately"?

Comment: edited.. basically checking if a string is approximately matching or not

Answer (score 3):

You could use function [`adist`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/adist.html) that computes the Levenshtein distance between the strings.

e.g. :

```
v <- c('aaa','aab','adb','aaa','bb')
distances <- adist(v)
row.names(distances) <- v
colnames(distances) <- v

> distances
    aaa aab adb aaa bb
aaa   0   1   2   0  3
aab   1   0   1   1  2
adb   2   1   0   2  2
aaa   0   1   2   0  3
bb    3   2   2   3  0
```

Interpretation of the result:

- `distances["adb","aaa"] = 2` , since two modifications are necessary on string `"adb"` to become `"aaa"` (`'d'` and `'b'` replaced by `'a'`).
- `distances["bb","aaa"] = 3` , since three modifications are necessary on string `"bb"` to become `"aaa"` (two `'b'` replaced by `'a'` and one further `'a'` added).

Comment: Note this computes aaa vs aab, and aab vs aaa, which are identical, and can add up with large comparisons.

Comment: Yes, they're equal as far as the costs for insertion/deletion/substitution remain equal. Anyway you can simply use adist('adb','aaa') to compute the distance from 'adb' to 'aaa' once (as basically does agrep internally)... of course this means you need to use apply's function to manage the various combinations on vector of characters.

Answer (score 0):

An implementation using `agrep`:

```
near.idx <- apply(     # Find matches
  combn(m6, 2), 2,     # compare all string combinations
  function(x) as.logical(length(agrep(x[[1]], x[[2]], 5L)))
)
apply(                 # Display matches
  combn(seq_along(m6), 2)[, near.idx], 2, 
  function(x) paste0(m6[x[[1]]], " **MATCHES** ", m6[x[[2]]])
)
```

Which produces:

```
[1] "PLOT#39 H#8-2-293/A4/A/ **MATCHES** PLOT #39 H #8-2-293/A4/A" 
[2] "PLOT #39 H #8-2-293/A4/A **MATCHES** PLOT NO-39 H#8-2-293/A4/"
[3] "PLOT NO 1030 BUNGLOW NO **MATCHES** PLOT NO 1030 BUNGLOW NO"  
[4] "PLOT NO 1030 BUNGLOW NO **MATCHES** PLOT 1030 BUNGLOW NO 3"   
[5] "PLOT NO 1030 BUNGLOW NO **MATCHES** PLOT 1030 BUNGLOW NO 3"
```

`agrep` does approximate matching between two strings.  You can tweak how aggressively it attempts to match with the `max.distance` and other parameters.  Also, here I just chose to print stuff out, but you could store the matches, or remove the matches from your original vector, whatever.